# "Failed to find Steam" when starting

Tags: steam, deus-ex

I have bought Deus Ex: Game of the Year edition on Steam and I am experiencing an issue that prevents me from playing. When I start the game I immediately get the following error;

[image: All aboard the fail boat]

The game then immediately quits. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have 64-bit Windows or have chosen a custom installation location for Steam, the game will "fail to find Steam" because it's only looking in the default locations.

[The solution below is from the official Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=26798133&postcount=4).

Users of 64-bit Windows will have Steam located here by default:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\steam
```

The solution is to add your Steam location to your path.

Here's how you modify the 'Path' environmental variable;

- Right-click on "Computer" (in XP it was called "My Computer") and click on Properties.
- in Vista / 7, on the left click on "Advanced System Settings". On XP, skip to the next step as you're already on the right screen.
- In the Advanced tab, you'll see a button for "Environment Variables". Click it.
- In the lower section of that new window, you should see something like "System Variables". Scroll through to find the one called "PATH". *You could probably create a user variable for this instead if you wanted*
- Highlight the entry for "PATH" and click "Edit...".
- You'll get a too-small text box that has a field on the top for "Variable Name" and a field under it for "Variable Value". Put your cursor into the "Variable Value" field and hit the [End] key so you know you're not inserting text in the middle of another entry. If you push the right arrow key it should not scroll.
- Add a semicolon [;] to separate your new entry from the others.
- Paste in the path to Steam, which for me is D:\Steam but if you've installed to the default location on a Windows 7 64 system will be:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam
  ```
- Press OK, and re-launch Steam so that it gets the new environment variables. (It might work without re-launching, but hey why not.)
- Run the game!

This should work with any custom location of Steam, for any games that have trouble finding Steam when they launch.

Comment: Yeah, it works!. I had this problem with a few other games, and solved it by starting steam in admin mode, but this solution is better and more permanent.

Comment: This looks a lot like this [forum post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=26798133&postcount=4)...this could be a complete random happenstance, but please, if you do use outside sources, be sure to attribute them. :D

Comment: I don't have a system variable marked PATH